# Reverting back to backup.txt for specific lines

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have `backup.txt`

```
five six seven
five six seven seven six five
five more here
What about FIVE fIve fivefive fivefivefive fIveFivefiVe?
```

and I new.txt

```
four six seven
four six seven seven six four
four more here
What about four four fourfour fourfourfour fourfourfour?
```

I want to revert lines 3 and 4 of my new text to how it was in the `backup.txt`

```
five more here
What about FIVE fIve fivefive fivefivefive fIveFivefiVe?
```

How do I accomplish this with `sed`?

So new.txt will look like

```
four six seven
four six seven seven six four
five more here
What about FIVE fIve fivefive fivefivefive fIveFivefiVe?
```

Comment: My immediate reaction is "you can't".  It depends on what you mean, but unless you have a record of the previous line 4 (in particular), you can't recover the case-sensitivity of the original given the case-insensitive appearance of the edited version.  Also, I'm assuming you mean that you've done a complete pass of the file, and then want to make another pass to undo it.  You can't meaningfully revert the content while you're editing; `sed` has no undo buffer mechanism or anything like it.  It's a non-interactive editor; there is no need for such a mechanism.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I don't think I was very clear in my question and I'm sorry. I have new.txt which the new text that I played around with using sed and I have backup.txt which was the original. Is there a way I could change lines 3 and 4 of my new text to how they were in backup.txt?

Comment: Oh.  Does this count?  `sed -n '1,2p; 7,8p' new.txt backup.txt`?  Don't print by default; print the first two lines (from `new.txt`); print the last two lines (from `backup.txt`).  It's not very flexible, but then neither is the scenario given.  Or you can apply the transform only to the first two lines: `sed -e '1,2s/five/four/g' backup.txt`.

Comment: Yes that works! Thanks! Would there be a way to save the new correct output to new.txt with -i? or some other method?

Comment: For the second command (redoing the edit), redirect `… > new.txt`.  For the first, you can't overwrite `new.txt`; redirect to another file and then move the new file over the old:  `… > alt.txt; mv alt.txt new.txt`.  Or `… > alt.txt; cp alt.txt new.txt; rm alt.txt`.  If there's a hard link to `new.txt`, this will preserve the link, but the `mv` would break it.  If, as is likely, there is no such link, then just use `mv`.

Answer (score 0):

In Your specific case

```
sed -n '1p;2p;7p;7p' new.txt backupt.txt
```

Will work as expected.